# Groupby and transpose or unstack in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, transpose

I have the following **Python** **pandas** dataframe:
There are more EventName's than shown on this date.
Each will have Race_Number = 'Race 1', 'Race 2', etc.
After a while the date increments.
[image].

I'm trying to create a dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

Each race has different numbers of runners.
Is there a way to do this in **pandas** ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I assumed output would be another DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from nltk import flatten
import copy

df = pd.DataFrame({'EventName': ['sydney', 'sydney', 'sydney', 'sydney', 'sydney', 'sydney'],
                   'Date': ['2019-01.01', '2019-01.01', '2019-01.01', '2019-01.01', '2019-01.01', '2019-01.01'],
                   'Race_Number': ['Race1', 'Race1', 'Race1', 'Race2', 'Race2', 'Race3'],
                   'Number': [4, 7, 2, 9, 5, 10]
                   })
print(df)

dic={}
for rows in df.itertuples():
    if rows.Race_Number in dic:
        dic[rows.Race_Number] = flatten([dic[rows.Race_Number], rows.Number])
    else:
        dic[rows.Race_Number] = rows.Number

copy_dic = copy.deepcopy(dic)
seq = np.arange(0,len(dic.keys()))
for key, n_key in zip(copy_dic, seq):
    dic[n_key] = dic.pop(key)

df = pd.DataFrame([dic])

print(df)
```

Comment: Hi BC Smith. Many thanks for your amazing effort.  When I ran your code I found it appends the next EventName 'race 1' numbers to the previous.  I have edited the question to reflect the fact that there are many 'Race 1s' etc. Perhaps I should split the dataframe after each EventName and apply your code?  What do you suggest?